# List and count unique words from a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, statistics, word-count

I want to take a Microsoft Word document and produce a spreadsheet of all the words contained in the document and the number of times each word appears.

e.g.,

```
cat    23
said   15
jumped 12
dog    7
```

Is this a no-brainer problem that can be accomplished in a simple, straightforward way using built-in functions and features of Word or Excel?

If not, is this functionality readily available in off-the-shelf tools (in which case, please advise what I should inquire about on the Software Recs site), or would custom programming be required?

Comment: Excel solution: Step 1: Parse the document into separate words in a spreadsheet column.  Step 2: The remainder of the solution is in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/518655/364367 (see its linked example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from VBA, one can develop such an application using API of OpenOffice to read the contents of the Word document; process it and export the results as a CSV file to open in a spreadsheet application.

However it's actually just a few line of codes if you're familiar with any programming language.
For example in Python you can easily do it like that:

Here we define a simple function which counts words given a list

```
def countWords(a_list):
    words = {}
    for i in range(len(a_list)):
        item = a_list[i]
        count = a_list.count(item)
        words[item] = count
    return sorted(words.items(), key = lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
```

The rest is to manipulate the content of the document.First paste it:

```
content = """This is the content of the word document. Just copy paste it. 
It can be very very very very long and it can contain punctuation 
(they will be ignored) and numbers like 123 and 4567 (they will be counted)."""
```

Here we remove the punctuation, EOL, parentheses etc. and then generate a word list for our function:

```
import re

cleanContent = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' ', content)

wordList = cleanContent.lower().split()
```

Then we run our function and store its result (word-count pairs) in another list and print the results:

```
result = countWords(wordList)

for words in result:
    print(words)
```

So the result is:

```
('very', 4)
('and', 3)
('it', 3)
('be', 3)
('they', 2)
('will', 2)
('can', 2)
('the', 2)
('ignored', 1)
('just', 1)
('is', 1)
('numbers', 1)
('punctuation', 1)
('long', 1)
('content', 1)
('document', 1)
('123', 1)
('4567', 1)
('copy', 1)
('paste', 1)
('word', 1)
('like', 1)
('this', 1)
('of', 1)
('contain', 1)
('counted', 1)
```

You can remove parentheses and comma using search/replace if you want.

All you need to do download [Python 3](http://www.python.org/download/), install it, open IDLE (comes with Python), replace the content of your word document and run the commands one at a time and in the given order.

Comment: Inside the `countWords(a_list)` function you can add this line `items = list(dict.fromkeys(a_list))` and loop for the unique words instead of looping all the text; e.g. `for i in range(len(items)):`

Answer (score 2):

Use VBA. 
A macro (subroutine) to do exactly what you request is on [this](http://word.tips.net/T001833_Generating_a_Count_of_Word_Occurrences.html) page:

```
Sub WordFrequency()
    Const maxwords = 9000          'Maximum unique words allowed
    Dim SingleWord As String       'Raw word pulled from doc
    Dim Words(maxwords) As String  'Array to hold unique words
    Dim Freq(maxwords) As Integer  'Frequency counter for unique words
    Dim WordNum As Integer         'Number of unique words
    Dim ByFreq As Boolean          'Flag for sorting order
    Dim ttlwds As Long             'Total words in the document
    Dim Excludes As String         'Words to be excluded
    Dim Found As Boolean           'Temporary flag
    Dim j, k, l, Temp As Integer   'Temporary variables
    Dim ans As String              'How user wants to sort results
    Dim tword As String            '

    ' Set up excluded words
    Excludes = "[the][a][of][is][to][for][by][be][and][are]"

    ' Find out how to sort
    ByFreq = True
    ans = InputBox("Sort by WORD or by FREQ?", "Sort order", "WORD")
    If ans = "" Then End
    If UCase(ans) = "WORD" Then
        ByFreq = False
    End If

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
    WordNum = 0
    ttlwds = ActiveDocument.Words.Count

    ' Control the repeat
    For Each aword In ActiveDocument.Words
        SingleWord = Trim(LCase(aword))
        'Out of range?
        If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z" Then
            SingleWord = ""
        End If
        'On exclude list?
        If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWord & "]") Then
            SingleWord = ""
        End If
        If Len(SingleWord) > 0 Then
            Found = False
            For j = 1 To WordNum
                If Words(j) = SingleWord Then
                    Freq(j) = Freq(j) + 1
                    Found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If Not Found Then
                WordNum = WordNum + 1
                Words(WordNum) = SingleWord
                Freq(WordNum) = 1
            End If
            If WordNum > maxwords - 1 Then
                j = MsgBox("Too many words.", vbOKOnly)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        ttlwds = ttlwds - 1
        StatusBar = "Remaining: " & ttlwds & ", Unique: " & WordNum
    Next aword

    ' Now sort it into word order
    For j = 1 To WordNum - 1
        k = j
        For l = j + 1 To WordNum
            If (Not ByFreq And Words(l) < Words(k)) _
              Or (ByFreq And Freq(l) > Freq(k)) Then k = l
        Next l
        If k <> j Then
            tword = Words(j)
            Words(j) = Words(k)
            Words(k) = tword
            Temp = Freq(j)
            Freq(j) = Freq(k)
            Freq(k) = Temp
        End If
        StatusBar = "Sorting: " & WordNum - j
    Next j

    ' Now write out the results
    tmpName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
    Documents.Add Template:=tmpName, NewTemplate:=False
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
    With Selection
        For j = 1 To WordNum
            .TypeText Text:=Trim(Str(Freq(j))) _
              & vbTab & Words(j) & vbCrLf
        Next j
    End With
    System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
    j = MsgBox("There were " & Trim(Str(WordNum)) & _
      " different words ", vbOKOnly, "Finished")
End Sub
```

Comment: Notes: (1) By design (but not documented), this routine will ignore (exclude) the words “the”, “a”, “of”, “is”, “to”, “for”, “by”, “be”, “and”, and “are”.  You can trivially edit the code to change this list.  (2) There appears to be a bug: a “word” is rejected as out of range if `If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z"`.  This results in words beginning with “z” being ignored.  A *very* quick experiment (I’m not going to dignify it by calling it a “test”) suggests that this can be fixed by changing `> "z"` to `>= "{"`.