# Microsoft Office Keyword Analysis

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, word-count

Is there a piece of software that will do keyword analysis on a batch of Microsoft Word files? In other words, I would simply like a word count on all words used. The objective is to identify keywords as the basis for creating a taxonomy.

Comment: This is very open-ended: What type of analysis did you want?

Comment: updated question to be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/251324/list-and-count-unique-words-from-a-word-document

Answer (score 1):

I use a Python script that uses the `docx.py` module (see [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx/0.1.2)) to read Word files and process the individual words for a related task. The key bits are in the following code (which only reads one .docx file given as the first command line argument, but could easily be expanded to count words in many files:

```
from docx import *
import sys

try:
    document = opendocx(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print('Could not open '+sys.argv[1])
    exit()

## Fetch all the text out of the document       
paratextlist = getdocumenttext(document)    

count = {}
for line in paratextlist:
    for word in line.rstrip().split():
        count{word} = count.get(word,0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [WordStat](http://www.provalisresearch.com/wordstat/WordstatFeatures.html) ?

Comment: Exactly right. Quite pricey though at ~$3000.