# Find the number of occurrence of a word in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can I count the amount of occurrence in Excel 2007? The desired outcome should be something like:

```
apple 1
berry 2
coconut 3
donut 2
grape 1
lime 1
```

I have tried `=COUNTIF($A:$A,A7)`, but that didn't gave the desired result.

#### Sample Data:

```
apple
berry
berry
coconut
coconut
coconut
donut
donut
grape
lime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `A7` with the row number for each row.

```
apple   =COUNTIF($A:$A,A1)
berry   =COUNTIF($A:$A,A2)
berry   =COUNTIF($A:$A,A3)
coconut =COUNTIF($A:$A,A4)
coconut =COUNTIF($A:$A,A5)
coconut =COUNTIF($A:$A,A6)
donut   =COUNTIF($A:$A,A7)
donut   =COUNTIF($A:$A,A8)
grape   =COUNTIF($A:$A,A9)
lime    =COUNTIF($A:$A,A10)
```

Comment: Does this give the desired outcome?

Comment: @pnuts: So actually no, but after removal of duplicates it will be.

Comment: @pnuts Thank you very much, I'm truly honoured and humbled by your comment :-)

Comment: @Jacob as pnuts mentioned, this answer was meant to be a pointer, since OP didn't make it clear whether the dupe entries were required or not, I thought I'll leave a first glimpse answer to see this is what the OP wanted. I didn't expect you to post another comprehensive answer, and I truly didn't expect the OP to accept this right away. Thanks.

Comment: The OP is right. I'm glad I was part of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following functions in microsoft excel:

- SUM
- IF
- FREQUENTY
- MATCH
- COUNTIF
- CONCATENATE

And prepare them like this:

1. Get all unique items: [SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A10,A1:A10,0),MATCH(A1:A10,A1:A10,0))>0,1))](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx#BMcount_the_number_of_unique_values_by_)
2. Count them: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,B1)`
3. Added them together: `=CONCATENATE(B1," ",C1)`

In Google Spreadsheet it would have been a bit easier:

5. Prepare all unique items: `=UNIQUE(A1:A10)`
6. Count them: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,B1)`
7. Added them together: `=CONCATENATE(B1," ",C1)`

See example I've prepared: [Find the number of occurrence of a word](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGYxemE1M3FkcWd6aGgzODhrVG5VT2c)