# Count how many times a text appears in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How do I count how many times each text appears in a column?
For example I have this column:

```
foo1
foo1
foo1
too2
foo1
too2
mmm
mmm
foo1
```

Now I like to excute a function that shows me this result:

```
foo1 = 4
mmm= 2
too2 =2
```

Can this be done in a single advanced function?
i did try with COUNTIF but then i need to do on each text instance.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A22601,"foo1")
```

but then i need to know which text's i have in each column.
what i want is function that will take the column and calculate each text how many instances it has in the column

Comment: This seems to be a common question and was answered [multiple times](http://superuser.com/questions/518632/find-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-word-in-excel-2007). Have a look at the `countif` statement

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

`foo1    4`,`foo1    4`,`mmm     2`,`mmm     2`,`mmm     2`,`too2    2`

etc?

Comment: Ahh... you need a Pivot table. Try this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you add a header row with a label to your data, you can build a pivot table

- click any cell in the column
- click Insert ribbon > Pivot Table
- In the field pane drag the field rom the top panel into the row box and then drag it into the value box

If you don't want a pivot table, you can create a list of unique values by selecting the data. Then click Data ribbon > Advanced (in the Sort & Filter group). Tick the box for "Unique records only". Also tick "Copy to another location" and in the "copy to" box specify a cell.
This will give you a list of unique text values.  Let's say this list starts in cell G3. In cell H3 you can then use a Countif like

=COUNTIF(A:A,G3)

and copy that down.

Comment: how can i sort the value box ? i can only sort the row box

Comment: click any cell in the column, then click Data > Sort

Comment: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVAFkMYEt44